# Как спарсить данные со страницы профиля insagram без API?

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, instagram

Нужно спарсить количество подписчиков произвольного профиля в инстаграм. По-моему это возможно сделать без авторизации и тем более API.

Я пробовал вот так:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'https://www.instagram.com/buzova86/';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://instagram.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'authority: www.instagram.com',
        'method: GET',
        'path: /buzova86/',
        'scheme: https',
        'content-length: 44',
        'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
        'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
        'accept-language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
        'sec-fetch-mode: navigate',
        'sec-fetch-user: ?1',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1'
        )
);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($data);
```

В ответ получал

```
string(2539) "HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/
Vary: Accept-Language, Cookie
Content-Language: ru
Date: Thu, 24 Oct 2019 08:36:14 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
content-security-policy: report-uri https://www.instagram.com/security/csp_report/; default-src 'self' https://www.instagram.com; img-src https: data: blob:; font-src https: data:; media-src 'self' blob: https://www.instagram.com https://*.cdninstagram.com https://*.fbcdn.net; manifest-src 'self' https://www.instagram.com; script-src 'self' https://instagram.com https://www.instagram.com https://*.www.instagram.com https://*.cdninstagram.com wss://www.instagram.com https://*.facebook.com https://*.fbcdn.net https://*.facebook.net 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' blob:; style-src 'self' https://*.www.instagram.com https://www.instagram.com 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src 'self' https://instagram.com https://www.instagram.com https://*.www.instagram.com https://graph.instagram.com https://*.graph.instagram.com https://*.cdninstagram.com https://api.instagram.com wss://www.instagram.com wss://edge-chat.instagram.com https://*.facebook.com https://*.fbcdn.net https://*.facebook.net chrome-extension://boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd blob:; worker-src 'self' blob: https://www.instagram.com; frame-src 'self' https://instagram.com https://www.instagram.com https://staticxx.facebook.com https://www.facebook.com https://web.facebook.com https://connect.facebook.net https://m.facebook.com; object-src 'none'; upgrade-insecure-requests
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 0
x-aed: 11
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-IG-Set-WWW-Claim
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=M16eDI8m7VNnGPFGjxXwS7bnrajiCpMw; Domain=.instagram.com; expires=Thu, 22-Oct-2020 08:36:14 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; Secure
Set-Cookie: rur=FTW; Domain=.instagram.com; HttpOnly; Path=/; Secure
Set-Cookie: mid=XbFifgAEAAF0VBO0hZSUdB6NI6TI; Domain=.instagram.com; expires=Sun, 21-Oct-2029 08:36:14 GMT; Max-Age=315360000; Path=/; Secure
X-FB-TRIP-ID: 1679558926
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 24 Oct 2019 08:36:14 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 105
```

Так же пробовал к ссылке добавлять '?__a=1', чтобы получилось https://www.instagram.com/buzova86/?__a=1 
Вот если перейти по этой ссылке это прям то что нужно, но пытаясь сделать все тоже самое с такой ссылкой, все равно ответ примерно тот же самый.

Comment: а где вы там по второй ссылке видите подписчиков? по крайней мере при условии, что вы не авторизованы

Comment: мне нужны не подписчики а их колличество, там это есть

Comment: я понял, но не нашел в каком поле. поэтому и спрашиваю

Comment: {"count":16396998}

Comment: только это число у Бузовой меняется чуть ли не каждую секунду)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как ни странно, у меня следующий примитивный код выдает искомое число.

```
$url = "https://www.instagram.com/buzova86/?__a=1";
$response = file_get_contents($url);

if($response){
    $data = json_decode($response, true);
    $followers = $data['graphql']['user']['edge_followed_by']['count'];
    print_r($followers);
}
```

может не стоит миллиард заголовков в запрос отправлять?

Comment: затестил, у меня в ответ пустота, то есть followers NULL(
при этом если посмотреть, что в $response (var_dump) у меня показывает "string(38416)", что может быть у меня не так не подскажите?

Comment: дак и что там у вас в `response` то получается? и что получается в `print_r($http_response_header);`

Comment: запустил ваш код на онлайн сервисе, все работает, может как то влияет, что этот код я тестирую на wordpress?

Comment: если делать print_r($response); - то пустота, если var_dump($response); - то string(38316) " "

Comment: а вы сделайте `file_put_contants("out.txt", $response)`. Но прежде посмотрите заголовки, как указано выше. мб у вас там тоже 302->400

Comment: только 302 выходит

Comment: тогда ждите специалистов по вордпрессу, я хз что там у вас происходит :)

Comment: Такое ощущение что просто ip моего хостинга в бане у instagram, потомучто др. сайты норм парсятся через file_get_contents

Comment: А вордпресс тут при чем? Через file_get_contents парсить инстраграм немного наивно - разик прокатит, может 2 и перестанет. А в курле надо играться с заголовками. Можно попробовать через прокси парсить

Comment: @РашенБеар а в `file_get_contents` типа с заголовками играться нельзя, или что?

Comment: @teran можно. Только это как копать траншею граблями

Comment: @РашенБеар не вижу принципиальной разницы, между тем чтобы устанавливать различные `CURL_OPT` и настройкой опций контекста для file_get_contents. Пока нет необходимости в мультикурле, то вообще пофигу с чем работать. разве что сравнить на конкретном примере, что из них будет быстрее. В большинстве случаев мб и curl, но не всегда. Если какие-то есть весомые доводы, то сообщите,а так ОБС какой-то.

Comment: WordPress тут ни при чём. Приведённый в ответе код будет работать и на WP-сайте.